# Magento 2 - 2.3.1. Warning "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 1.4.1"

Tags: jquery, magento2.3.1

We are seeing this `Magento 2 - 2.3.1. Warning "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 1.4.1"` on fresh 2.3.1 install

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 1.4.1
jquery-migrate.js:45 JQMIGRATE: jQuery.attrFn is deprecated
migrateWarn @ jquery-migrate.js:45
jquery-migrate.js:47 console.trace
migrateWarn @ jquery-migrate.js:47
```

Is this a normal message or can we disable this?

(there was no prior M2 version, direc 2.3.1 install via composer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit file `lib/web/jquery/jquery-migrate.js`

Look for at line 19

```
// Set to true to prevent console output; migrateWarnings still maintained
jQuery.migrateMute = false;
```

and change to true

```
// Set to true to prevent console output; migrateWarnings still maintained
jQuery.migrateMute = true;
```

We saw this during developer mode. No idea if it would log also in production mode. But we would rather not see any logging/output in console especially when this is a clean 2.3.1. install from repo.

Comment: This is a core file that is placed there on a `composer install` and will be overwritten on a reinstall which would undo this solution. A proper solution should be without modifying a core file

Comment: @KlaasvanderWeij Not when you copied it over to your custom folder.

Comment: Maybe add that advise with an example to the answer?